# Creating nodes and edges by reading sparse matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a matrix in the following format, in which the number indicates the connection between the corresponding elements. For example, A and C are connected and A has 3 Cs in its surroundings, similarly, A has 3 Ds in its surroundings and B has 3Cs and 3Ds in its surroundings. We can see that A and B share C, D. In my case if they have two common points of sharing, I can say they are sharing the edge, I mean A and B share the edge (because they have C and D as a common point).

```
  A   B   C   D
A   0   0   3   3
B   0   0   3   3
C   3   3   0   0
D   3   3   0   0
```

I want to encode this information and build a table saying A has 6 surroundings, B has six surroundings and they share the edge. Can anyone please suggest share some ideas to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider your example as an [Adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) then you can use [from_scipy_sparse_matrix](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_scipy_sparse_matrix.html) to generate the associated graph. The problem is reduced to loop over the set of vertex and counting whether there is edge between them.